# Integrability of the logarithm wrt a finite Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, integration

I have a finite Borel measure $d\phi$ on $(0,1)$, i.e. $\int_0^1 d\phi(x) < \infty$.

Is it also true that $\int_0^1 \log (x) d\phi(x) < \infty$?

The function $\log$ is integrable at 0, so intuitively it should be true, but I don't see a rigorous argument. Arguments or counterexamples are welcome.

Comment: $d\phi(x)=(1/(x\ln^2 x))\, dx$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the measure that puts mass $\frac{1}{2^n}$ at the point $e^{-2^n}$.

By a similar argument, for any unbounded measurable $f$ on any measurable space, there is a finite measure $\mu$ such that $\int |f|\,d\mu = \infty$.